# Showing every state in an intuitionistic model verifies ¬¬p → p

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, modal-logic, intuitionistic-logic

I'm working on a question in the field of intuitionistic logic:

In an intuitionistic model, assume p ∨ ¬p is verified at the root state. Give a brief argument showing that every state in the model verifies ¬¬p → p. (You will need to exploit the semantic clauses for ∨, ¬, and →.)

The semantic clauses are these:

1. s ⊧ A ∨ B = + iff s ⊧ A = + or s ⊧ B = +
2. s ⊧ ¬A = + iff t ⊧ A = – for all t such that Rst
3. s ⊧ A → B = + iff, for all t such that Rst, either t ⊧ A = – or t ⊧
   B = +

but I don't have a clue how to turn that into an argument. If anyone can help I'd be really grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. Please take a look at this guide to [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and please use MathJax to format mathematical symbols in your questions. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In particular, instead of writing ["I don't have a clue"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/7062), you should share what you've tried so far and any thoughts you have about the problem. In this case, there's an obvious place to start: unwind the definitions. If the root state satisfies $p\lor \lnot p$, what does this mean about the model? What would it mean to show that a state satisfies $\lnot\lnot p\rightarrow p$?